# Как запустить React приложение

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, консоль

Только начинаю изучать React и столкнулся с такой проблемой, еще вчера я вводил в терминал npm run build  и код запускался, но сегодня когда я открыл VS code и ввел ту же команду, то вылетает ошибка вот что пишет в консоли:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "build"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
```

в файле json у меня все на месте

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},
если вы знаете еще способы запускать React приложение буду рад услышать.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). начните с заголовка.

Comment: что не так с заголовком? к чему вообще ваш комментарий?

Comment: "проблема с тем-то" - это очень плохой заголовок для вопроса.

Comment: проверьте папку из которой запускаете, должна быть та же, в которой находится `package.json`

Comment: npm run build вместо npm build